# Как узнать, чем занят порт, который использует денвер?

Tags: denwer, веб-сервер

Привет всем! У меня такая проблема: после установки визуал студио 2010 экспресс и всех программ ей необходимых, денвер не запускается. Когда у меня стояла визуал студия 2008, эти проблемы я решал, останавливая сервер в диспетчере служб iss. Как быть?

Answer (score 3):

В командной строке наберите `netstat –ano` и всё будет ясно.

Comment: не 
>netstat -ano
а 

    NETSTAT -a -n -o

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая программа [TCPview](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb897437), должна помочь вам в данном вопросе!

Answer (score 1):

Скайпом с очень высокой вероятностью ))

Потыкайте настройки, там это отключается.

Answer (score 0):

Просто попробуйте перевести Денвер на другой порт,например 8080 в apache/conf/**httpd.conf**
Скайп постоянно не дружит с ним,С апатчем)

Comment: В скайпе в "продвинутых настройках" можно отключить использование портов 80 и 443. После этого апач будет работать как часы...

Answer (score 0):

Если останавливал iss, чтобы работал денвер, то он на пару пытались сеть на 80 порт. Как сказал [[@R2Dtw](/users/3316/r2dtw)](/users/3316/r2dtw), переназначь в конфиге порт на 8080 или любой другой.

Comment: А теперь апач выводит: `[notice] Disabled use of acceptEx<> WinSock2 API`

Comment: Попробуйте в php.ini, закоментировать строку Listen 127.0.0.1:8080 и перезапустить.Не знаю когда у меня стояла Visual 2010 и OpenServer проблем не было.

Comment: Или выполнить netsh winsock reset при выключенном денвере.

Comment: в php.ini я такую строчку не нашел(((

Comment: не в php.ini а в конфиге апача

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте порт `netstat -a`. 
Если вам мешает встроенный в VS IIS - смените его порт (как это сделать, должно быть на сайте microsoft, крайний вариант - гугл всенайдущ).