# Не запускается Denwer(точнее Apache)

Tags: apache, denwer

Здравствуйте,при запуске denwer'а не запускается apache.В чем может быть дело?Порт свободен.
[image: Ошибка]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Вот тут гляньте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/36447/Как-узнать-чем-занят-порт-который-использует-денвер

Comment: Откуда такая уверенность, что пор свободен?

Comment: @AK Пробивал,а затем еще и ставил другие порты,которые точно свободные для резерва(из этого можно сделать вывод,что дело не в порте)

Comment: @Xomka Понятно. А то я уже хотел писать, что служба BranchCache держит порт или советы давать как посмотреть кто-держит-порт.

Answer (score 3):

Необходимо было зайти vhosts.conf и посмотреть какой из сайтов занимает не тот ip, затем пройти в папку с сайтом и удалить файл .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

В файле usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf

найди строки:

```
#Listen $&{ip:-127.0.0.1}:$&{port:-80}
#NameVirtualHost $&{ip:-127.0.0.1}:$&{port:-80}
#<VirtualHost $&{ip:-127.0.0.1}:$&{port:-80}>
```

и

```
#Listen $&{ip:-127.0.0.1}:$&{port_ssl:-443}
#NameVirtualHost $&{ip:-127.0.0.1}:$&{port_ssl:-443}
#<VirtualHost $&{ip:-127.0.0.1}:$&{port_ssl:-443}>
```

И замени 80 и 443 например на 96.
В браузере потом вбивай http://localhost:96